# Connect compressor directly to PC sound card

Tags: audio, sound, audio-interfaces, compression, xlr

Imagine that you have:

- A microphone (XLR)
- Audio compressor (Behringer MDX2600)
- PC internal sound card (like Creative Sound Blaster Z)

Is it possible to connect it like this?: 
*Mic(XLR)* **>** *Compressor* **>** *PC internal sound card*

P.s. I know that it is possible connect it to USB audio interface instead of internal SC.

Comment: You'll probably need a preamp between the mic and the compressor, and whether you can connect the compressor to the sound card depends entirely on the types of inputs it has.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need a preamp between the microphone and the compressor.

You will also likely need a balance to unbalance conversion cable between the compressor output and the PC Sound Card as the inputs are generally unbalanced.

Connections are:

- 1--1 (GND)
- 2--2 (+SIG)
- 3--1 (-SIG)